# jqrid generate xml from grid data

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying for a few hours now to generate an xml string  from my grid's data , when the columns names will be the tag names and the content of the grid will be inside of them.
my grid is initialized with xmlReader.
I tried using:

> var dataFromGrid = {row: grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data') };
>      var xmldata = xmlJsonClass.json2xml (dataFromGrid, '\t');
>                                      alert(xmldata);

but it did not work for me. 
how can this be done? it will be better not using json, if it's possible.
Thank's In advance.

#### Update:

This is my code: I'm using datatype xml.

```
Query("#signatory2_payment").jqGrid({
                url:'loadgrid.jsp?type=3',
                datatype: "xml",
                direction:"rtl",
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                colNames:['group_order','claim','beneficiary_description','insurance_code_description'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'group_order',xmlmap:'group_order', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'claim',xmlmap:'claim', width:70, align:"right",sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'beneficiary_description',xmlmap:'beneficiary_description', width:120, align:"right",sorttype:"string"},
                    {name:'insurance_code_description',xmlmap:'insurance_code_description', width:120, align:"right",sorttype:"string"}},
                ],
                xmlReader: {
                      root:"payments",
                      row:"payment",
                      page:"payments>page",
                      total:"payments>total",
                      records:"payments>records",
                      repeatitems:false
                  },
                multiselect: false,
                autowidth: true,
                forceFit: false,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                caption: "&nbsp;xxxxxx&nbsp;"
            });
```

If i understood you correctly it will work only on local data?
What is the solution for data that is not local?
Thank's again.

Comment: If you fill the grid **once** and use no server side data paging or server side searching, than probably you should just add `loadonce:true` to your grid. It could solve your problem. You can add additionally parameters like `rowNum:10` and `rowList:[10,20,100,1000]`, which gives you **local** data paging, sorting and after small modifications also local searching/filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725898/jgrid-problem-generating-xml/3753451#3753451). You will find here a working demo which do what you need.

**UPDATED:** It is important, that you include definition of `jqGrid` in your question. The `data` parameter will be filled only in case of local data (for example if you use `datatype:"local"`, `datatype:"xmlstring"` or use `loadonce:true` additional parameter which changes the `datatype` to `datatype:"local"` after the first load of data. So if my old answer will help you not you should append your question with additional informations.