# jqgrid xmlJsonClass.json2xml set tag names

Tags: jqgrid

My question is regarding [xml generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804747/jqgrid-generate-xml-from-grid-data-problem)
 question.

How can I change the tag name from "row" to another name ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems me prity simple. You can just modify the code of `MyExportToXml` to about following

```
var MyExportToXml = function (grid) {
    var dataFromGrid={gridRow:grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data')};
    var xmldata='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<myRows>\n'+
                xmlJsonClass.json2xml (dataFromGrid, '\t') + '</myRows>';
    alert(xmldata);
};
```

then you will have `<gridRow>` elements instead of `<row>`. See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportInXm1.htm).