# jqgrid table export as example

Tags: jqgrid

1.Can i use my jqgrid as a html form and i want a xml(output) as we give input to that after  updating updated values are in xml with same signature as we give input.

2.it is possible to use lov inside the table.

Comment: What kind of grid you use? (local, remore, do you use `loadonce:true`? Do you use grouping, subgrids, tree grids and so on?) Do you really need XML and not JSON? Which editing mode you use? Why you use local editing and not save the data directly on the server? What you mean under "lov inside the table"?

Comment: actually i want to use this grid as a html form for our project.grid is always loading remote data.i dont use grouping,subgrid,treegrid. I really need xml because we operate on large data so i prefer xml. i want to save data directly to server.( kindly send example for send data to server after submit)lov means list ot values it is ajax based component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data from the grid for example with respect of [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data). If you would use the method without additional parameters (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)) the whole grid data will be returned. In case of the usage of local data or `loadonce:true` the usage of `getGridParam` with the 'data' parameter will be even better.

After you will have the data in an an JavaScript object you can use `xmlJsonClass.json2xml` to convert the data to XML. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842360/jqgrid-xmljsonclass-json2xml-set-tag-names/4842543#4842543) for the code example). See additionally [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportSelectedInXmlWithAttrib.htm) and [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportInXmlWithCDATA.htm) another answers which questions I can't currently find.